# Github - Git Push Error

Tags: git, github

So I am on a branch called 'test_branch'.

I do `git add .` and `git commit` and everything works fine.

But when I do `git push`, it gives me the error :

```
! [rejected]        acceptance -> acceptance (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:company/sample.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Doing `git pull` shows me that everything is up-to-date, and doing a push after that, gives me the same error as above.

Can somebody please help me with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to push to master or to a remote branch?

Comment: I'm trying to push to a remote branch ... origin/test_branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `git push` without any arguments, its behavior depends on the value of the `push.default` setting.  The default value of `push.default` is `matching`, which, according to [`git help config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), does the following:

> `matching` -- push all branches having the same name in both ends.  This is for those who prepare all the branches into a publishable shape and then push them out with a single command.  It is not appropriate for pushing into a repository shared by multiple users, since locally stalled branches will attempt a non-fast forward push if other users updated the branch.

In other words, if your local repository has a branch named `acceptance` and the remote repository has a branch named `acceptance`, then `git push` will try to make the remote `acceptance` branch match your `acceptance` branch even if you don't have `acceptance` checked out.

So, my guess is that you checked out `acceptance` at some point in the past, but someone else on the project (or maybe you from a different clone of the repository) pushed new commits to `acceptance`.  This caused your local `acceptance` branch to be behind the remote `acceptance` branch.  Now whenever you type `git push`, your Git tries to back up the remote `acceptance` branch to the version you have in your local repository.

To fix, I recommend setting `push.default` to `simple` (or `upstream` if `simple` isn't available in your Git version -- it was only added in 1.7.11).

Comment: `git config push.default upstream` worked like a charm. Thanks so much !!

Answer (score 1):

There probably is a branch you have to merge with to be able to push a fast-forwardable commit. To find out, first do

```
$ git fetch
```

Then do

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
```

You should see that the branch you are trying to push is not in the same line and ahead of the remote branch you are trying to merge with.

By the way, `git push` by itself always pushes all of your tracked branches to their origin/ counterparts, and you might have branches that aren't up to date with their origin counterparts. In that case, just ignore the warning. You can make this warning less wordy by:

```
$ git config advice.pushNonFastForward false
```

But I now see that your real problem is probably that test_branch doesn't get pushed with `git push`. To fix that, type:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream test_branch origin/test_branch
```